# pie chart getting full block color in IE9 in Highhcarts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

pie chart getting full block color in IE9 in High charts when used High charts version 5.0.8 and it worked good in High charts version 3.0.10.Please help me.

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle with this pie? Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you are using the styled version of the library instead of the in-line style version.